# Table cells not aligning vertically

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm not able to get my table cells contents to align correctly.
I want the text and images in my cells to align to the bottom.
The images also have a style:

Code:

CSS file:

```
#pagy3 table tr td {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
    width: 25%;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

HTML file:

```
 <div id="pagy3">

 <table align="center" border=1;>
     <col width="180px">
     <col width="180px">
     <col width="180px">
     <col width="180px">
     <tr>
        <td colspan=4>
            <h2>Title</h2>
        </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Image<br>text</td>
        <td>Image<br>text</td>
        <td>Image<br>text</td>
        <td>Image<br>text</td>
     </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try ...

```
vertical-align: bottom;
```

It looks like you are aligning to the wrong elements, possibly ...

- bottom: The bottom of the element is aligned with the lowest element on the line.
- text-bottom: The bottom of the element is aligned with the bottom of the **parent element's font**.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. BTW, is it at all possible to have the text in my table aligned to the bottom and the images in the middle? I tried: #page3 table tr td.image {vertical-align: middle;}, but that doesn't do anything. I'm totally new to css/html, having used frontpage for more than 10 years.

Comment: If you build a jsFiddle, or something like that, someone will give you that answer.  That type of alignment can get a bit tricky.

Comment: You might consider breaking the image and text into two rows ... then the alignment could be separated correctly.

Answer (score 2):

```
vertical-align: text-bottom;
```

That aligns elements to the bottom of the parents font.

```
vertical-align: bottom;
```

Aligns ALL elements in the container to the BOTTOM of the container. You probably want to use **vertical-align:bottom** instead.

Comment: Thanks Cliff. That worked. I didn't down vote you, don't even think I could if I wanted to. Not enough credits for up voting.

Comment: :D The *"community bot"* are the terrifying human *bots* that don't like same-answer answers if they don't add some particular value that make one's answer different from the already answered one.

Comment: Well if they had looked carefully they might have noticed that I was writing mine while the other was being posted and which, in its initial form was simply a one line answer that didn't explain why one worked and the other didn't

Comment: @CliffRibaudo hehehh yeh, probably they've looked carefully :D